# Django image is not displaying in developement environment

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying add image in model with an Imagefield

Folder Structure:

```
/base
    /migrations
    /tempelates
    ...
    admin.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    ...
/env
/static
    /images
        avatar.png
    /styles
    /png
/networth_tracker/
/tempelates/
db.sqlite3
manage.py
pp1.jpg  #image I uploaded from admin site
pp2.jpg  #image I uploaded from admin site
pp3.jpg  #image I uploaded from admin site
```

/base/models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True,default="avatar.png")
    ....

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

/networth_tracker/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIAFILES_DIRS)
```

/networth_tracker/settings.py

```
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR / "static/images"
...
```

Issue:

1. I upload an image from admin site
2. I tried to view the image directly in admin site and getting following error
   -- it searching for image in 127.0.0.1/images/pp1.jpg and returning page not found
3. Image is uploading in / (root dir) instead of /static/images/ (media dir)
   [image: Error on clicking image link from django admin site]

I tried alternatives which is also not worked:

1. I tried by adding upload_to="static/images" in ImageField
   models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
   ...
   logo = models.ImageField(null=True,default="avatar.png", upload_to="static/images")
   ...
    
   class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

2. It uploaded the image into the static/images/ folder, but getting following error
   [image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. Do you want to be able to upload files from django admin and see it? (That would be media files) or do you want to see your static images whenever you run your app (static files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MEDIAFILES_DIRS` - there is no such option. You need to set `STATIC_ROOT`, `MEDIA_ROOT`.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_ROOT)